# viewWillTransitionToSize out of sync animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I added a view as subview to the mainscreen like this

```
UIWindow *currentWindow= [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
[currentWindow addSubview:visualEffectView];
```

When the view transition the vieWillTransition is called, when that happens I do:

```
visualEffectView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
labelBlurView.frame= CGRectMake(size.width/2 -15, size.height/2 - 80, 40, 20);
```

As you can see I am trying to show a blurview above my current view, but the problem comes when my current view changes orientation from landscape to portrait. My blur view frame gets resized after the mainView is resized. Hence I am left with a small milisecond in which I can see the mainView behind the blur view(without the blur covering it) on the right side of the screen. The blur view then changes its frame and extends to the right covering the complete view later.

I wanted to make such that the blurview frame is resized at the similar pace to the mainview or even quicker such that I do not end up with with visible areas and the blurview always keeps covering the mainView.

Comment: Maybe try to manually resize it in - `(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration` as this method gets call just BEFORE the actual orientation change